# Magento mod_rewrite redirecting page.asp?query to index.php/product/

Tags: mod-rewrite, magento

We're moving a client from an ASP based shop, to Magento and would like to rewrite the old shop links to the new format. We're changing DNS for the domain, so links that Google has already indexed will turn up as 404 in the new shop obviously.

Format on the old shop is: page.asp?objectid=8&dataowner=webshopproduct&dataaction=showproduct&dataactionitem=1698&zcs=2

Format on the new shop is: index.php/catalog/product/view/id/0000/import-

I've tried something like:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*showproduct.*
RewriteRule ^index.php/catalog/product/view/id/0000/imported-([^/]*)$ page.asp?objectid=8&dataowner=webshopproduct&dataaction=showproduct&dataactionitem=$1&zcs=2

And variants of above, but I can't get it working.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The above link, to the new shop, should've been: index.php/catalog/product/view/id/0000/import-dataactionitem_id_from_url_here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following ( you can extend if you wish )

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} objectid=(.*)
RewriteRule ^grab(.*) /index.php/catalog/product/view/id/%1
```

[Htaccess Tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: Hi

That doesn't appear to be working.

I get a 404 when commenting out Magento's RewriteRule to index.php.

Comment: The standard htaccess file is here: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5/.htaccess

This is how mine looks also.

I'm placing your lines, right above the:

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

And I just get a "Page cannot be found" (in Magento). If I comment out Magento's index.php [L] rule above, I get a 404 page from the server.

Comment: Benny, I gave you link, could you please research in there as well.